# Query on undefined boundary - is this possible?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, boundary-value-problem

I have a reaction-diffusion PDE of the form

$\frac{dp}{dt} = D \nabla p - \frac{a\Omega p}{p + k}$

where $D$, $a$, $k$ and $\Omega$ are all known constants. Initially, in the region of interest, $p(r,0) = 0$ . There is a boundary at zero at a constant value of $p_{o}$ (Dirichlet condition?) so I suspect I write $p(0,t) = p_{o}$ for one of my boundary conditions. The problem is the other one; from my understanding, I could need two boundary conditions to specify the problem and apply a numerical solution, and I only have one. I know approximately where the other boundary $L$ is (such that $p(L) = 0$) but I wonder if there's a better way to do this than just guess?

Specifically, as the solution diffuses into the region of interest, it is consumed at a rate $\frac{ap}{p + k}$ , and eventually reaches a point $L$  where $p(L) = 0$ and it can no longer diffuse - is it possible to use this knowledge to specify the second boundary, or is trial and error the only way? Any insight people can share would be greatly appreciated!

Note: The other constants are all known; $D = 2 \times 10^{-9}$ , $a = 7.5 \times 10^{-7}$, $\Omega = 3.0318 \times 10^{7}$, $k = 1$ and $p_{o} = 100$.

Comment: So your region of interest is $x\in[0,L]$, $t\ge0$ with an unknown $L$, is that it? You say it eventually reaches a point $L$ where $p(L)=0$, but that is assumed to hold at $t=0$. And for *any* $t>0$, you will have $p(L,t)>0$ (assuming $p_0>0$). From your description, it could be that you really want a Neumann condition at $x=L$. I.e., $\partial_x p(L)=0$, so there is no flow there. I see no way you can deduce even an approximate location of $L$ from the data given.

Comment: That's a good point - I think a no-flow condition would be fine too; I don't see anyway to find $L$ myself but wanted to check there wasn't some obvious solution I was missing!

Comment: But you *can* make meaningful statements about the approximate time it will take for noticable amounts of substance to reach $x=L$. But it must be approximate, since the concentration there will increase gradually.

Comment: BTW, you can rescale $x$ and $t$ to get the problem on the form $\partial p/\partial t=\nabla p-p/(p+1)$ (I notice that $k=1$ already, otherwise you could achieve that by rescaling $p$ as well.) This sort of scaling simplifies some analysis. (Do you have some *approximate* idea what the size of $L$ is?)